# Select rounded time value

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of object like this one:

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| ID          | Value      | Time                | 
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 1           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:05:35 |
| 2           | 2          | 2019-03-07 20:06:09 |  
| 5           | 5          | 2019-03-07 20:11:27 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:13:30 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:13:41 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:17:00 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:22:20 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:23:05 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:27:35 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:27:37 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:28:01 |
| 7           | 5          | 2019-03-07 20:37:19 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:37:27 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:37:54 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:40:11 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:44:00 |
| 8           | 3          | 2019-03-07 20:45:00 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:47:41 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:48:43 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:48:51 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:51:11 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:54:46 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:55:36 |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
```

How to select records 15/30 minutes apart and round the time and take first value which is closest to rounded time?

The result should be something like this:

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| ID          | Value      | Time                | 
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 1           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:00:00 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:15:00 |
| 7           | 5          | 2019-03-07 20:30:00 |
| 8           | 3          | 2019-03-07 20:45:00 |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
```

So far I have this:

```
List<Dates> SortedList = dates.OrderBy(o => o.Time).ToList();
var datax = SortedList.GroupBy(cd => new {
Date = cd.Time.AddSeconds(-cd.Time.Second)
       .AddMinutes(-cd.Time.Minute % 15),
        CounterName = cd.Time,
        Value = cd.Value
        }).Select(g =>new {
        Date = g.Key.Date,
        CounterName = g.Key.CounterName,
        Value = g.Key.Value                
});
```

**UPDATE**

@Rik's soultions works perfect but on different time there are some gaps like missing 21:00:00, 21:30:00, 22:00:00, 22:30:00, 23:00:00...

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| ID          | Value      | Time                | 
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 1           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:39:15 |
| 2           | 2          | 2019-03-07 20:54:17 |  
| 5           | 5          | 2019-03-07 21:09:16 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 21:24:17 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 21:39:17 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 21:54:18 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 22:09:19 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 22:24:19 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 22:39:20 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 22:54:20 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 23:09:21 |
| 7           | 5          | 2019-03-07 23:24:20 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 23:39:22 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 23:54:23 |   
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
```

Output is:

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| ID          | Value      | Time                | 
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 1           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:40:00 |
| 8           | 3          | 2019-03-07 20:50:00 |
| 7           | 5          | 2019-03-07 21:20:00 |
| 8           | 3          | 2019-03-07 21:40:00 |
| 8           | 3          | 2019-03-07 21:50:00 |
| 8           | 3          | 2019-03-07 22:10:00 |
| 8           | 3          | 2019-03-07 22:20:00 |
```

**UPDATE - Working code**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    round();

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static Dates GetNearestRecord(DateTime dateTime, IEnumerable<Dates> records)
{
    var nearestRecord = records.OrderBy(r => Math.Abs((r.Time - dateTime).TotalSeconds)).First();
    return new Dates() { ID = nearestRecord.ID, Value = nearestRecord.Value, Time = dateTime };
}
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GenerateIntervals(DateTime from, DateTime to, TimeSpan interval)
{
    DateTime current = NearestInterval(from, interval);
    DateTime last = NearestInterval(to, interval);
    while (current <= last)
    {
        yield return current;
        current = current.Add(interval);
    }
}
public static DateTime NearestInterval(DateTime value, TimeSpan interval)
{
    var temp = value.Add(new TimeSpan(interval.Ticks / 2));
    var time = new TimeSpan((temp.TimeOfDay.Ticks / interval.Ticks) * interval.Ticks);

    return value.Date.Add(time);
}
private static void round()
{

    List<Dates> dates = Dates.GetDates();

    var first = dates.Min(r => r.Time);
    var last = dates.Max(r => r.Time);
    var interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

    var intervals = GenerateIntervals(first, last, interval);
    var nearestRecords = intervals.Select(i => GetNearestRecord(i, dates));
}


public class Dates
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public static List<Dates> GetDates()
    {
        string input =
            "| 1           | 31         | 2019-03-07 20:39:15 |\n" +
            "| 2           | 12         | 2019-03-07 20:54:16 |\n" +
            "| 5           | 33         | 2019-03-07 21:09:16 |\n" +
            "| 7           | 11         | 2019-03-07 21:24:17 |\n" +
            "| 8           | 9          | 2019-03-07 21:39:18 |\n" +
            "| 7           | 14         | 2019-03-07 21:54:18 |\n" +
            "| 8           | 15         | 2019-03-07 22:09:19 |\n" +
            "| 7           | 16         | 2019-03-07 22:24:19 |\n" +
            "| 8           | 31         | 2019-03-07 22:39:20 |\n" +
            "| 7           | 3          | 2019-03-07 22:54:20 |\n" +
            "| 8           | 34         | 2019-03-07 23:09:21 |\n" +
            "| 7           | 10         | 2019-03-07 23:24:20 |\n" +
            "| 8           | 17         | 2019-03-07 23:39:22 |\n" +
            "| 7           | 18         | 2019-03-07 23:54:23";

        List<Dates> dates = new List<Dates>();

        string line = "";
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] lineArray = line.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            Dates newDate = new Dates()
            {
                ID = int.Parse(lineArray[0]),
                Value = int.Parse(lineArray[1]),
                Time = DateTime.Parse(lineArray[2])
            };

            dates.Add(newDate);
        }
        return dates;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the second records not be ` 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:15:00 |` as per expected output?

Comment: hm... actually not, because 20:13:41 is more close to 20:15:00 than 20:17:00. Between 20:13:41 and 20:15:00 difference is 1:19 and between 20:15:00 and 20:17:00 is 2 minutes

Comment: What are your priorities? Does this need to run fast or do you want something that is easy to read? Also can 1 entry appear multiple times in the result (if it's closest to both)? If there are no entries between 20:15 and 20:45 for example, what should be displayed for the 20:30 result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a method that will return the nearest quarter for a given `DateTime`

```
public static DateTime NearestQuarter(DateTime value)
{
    var temp = value.AddMinutes(7).AddSeconds(30);
    return new DateTime(temp.Year, temp.Month, temp.Day, temp.Hour, (temp.Minute / 15) * 15, 0);
}
```

You can then group your records by their `NearestQuarter` value:

```
var groupedByNearestQuarter = records.GroupBy(r => NearestQuarter(r.Time));
```

Next, we want to determine the which record in the group is closest to the nearest quarter and return a new `Record` whose `Time` property is the quarter in question. Let's create a method for that, too:

```
public Record GetNearestRecord(DateTime dateTime, IEnumerable<Record> records)
{
    var nearestRecord = records.OrderBy(r => Math.Abs((r.Time - dateTime).TotalSeconds)).First();
    return new Record() { Id = nearestRecord.Id, Value = nearestRecord.Value, Time = dateTime };
}
```

Finally, we can combine these two methods in a single LINQ query:

```
var nearestQuarterRecords = records.GroupBy(
    r => NearestQuarter(r.Time),
    r => r,
    GetNearestRecord);
```

**EDIT** 
If you want to make sure your result contains a element for every interval, start by generating the intervals and select the nearest record:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GenerateIntervals(DateTime from, DateTime to, TimeSpan interval)
{
    DateTime current = NearestInterval(from, interval);
    DateTime last = NearestInterval(to, interval);
    while (current <= last)
    {
        yield return current;
        current = current.Add(interval);
    }
}
```

Where `NearestInterval` is a generalized version of the `NearestQuarter` method above:

```
public static DateTime NearestInterval(DateTime value, TimeSpan interval)
{
    var temp = value.Add(new TimeSpan(interval.Ticks/2));
    var time = new TimeSpan((temp.TimeOfDay.Ticks / interval.Ticks) * interval.Ticks);

    return value.Date.Add(time);
}
```

Usage:

```
var first = records.Min(r => r.Time);
var last = records.Max(r => r.Time);
var interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

var intervals = GenerateIntervals(first, last, interval);
var nearestRecords = intervals.Select(i => GetNearestRecord(i, records))
```

Note that this solution does performs an `OrderBy` over all records for every interval. This is therefore not the most efficient approach, but at least the code is pretty clear.

If the records are ordered by time it's possible to achieve the same result by enumeration the records just once, which is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: this works perfect, but I noticed one problem. I've set time to 10 minutes and then i get some gaps like 20:40:00, 20:50:00, 21:10:00, 21:20:00, 21:40:00 but on little bit different data set, with different times. Notice that sometimes time jumps for 20 minutes, not 10 (see my updated post)

Comment: If you want to make sure your result contains a element for every interval, start by generating the intervals: see edit.

Comment: NearestInterval is is new method or?

Comment: Ah, yes; it's a generalized version of `GetNearestQuarter`. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Works perfect... but one more question; how come this only works for certain intervals? Changing timespan for 10 minutes works fine, for 5 also... but for 15 or 30, or 45 doesn't.

Comment: Could you be more specific? For me it's working fine for those intervals.

Comment: For example if I want to change interval then I change here `var interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);` Then I run this and `var nearestRecords = intervals.Select(i => GetNearestRecord(i, dates));` is empty. If I change back to 5 minutes or 10 minutes than there are some data in `nearestRecords`. The dataset for testing is always  same. See updated post.

Comment: perfect... This works excellent. But there is a small mistake in NearestInterval method. If the last time is like 2019-03-07 23:54:23 then the next rounded time should be 2019-03-08 00:00:00 but this method returns 2019-03-07 00:00:00 and I get a null dataset. Then I modified little bit return value `return temp.Date.Add(time);` See here https://dotnetfiddle.net/gUSs3r

Answer (score 1):

You can try `GroupBy`, the only difficulty is to implement grouping criterium:

```
 private static DateTime RoundToMinutes(DateTime value, int threshold = 15) {
   var shift = threshold * 
    (int)((value - value.Date).TotalMinutes / threshold +
          ((value - value.Date).TotalMinutes % threshold >= threshold / 2.0 ? 1 : 0));

   return value.Date.AddMinutes(shift);
 }
```

If we want a *closest* item to the key, we have to implement `ArgMin` as well.

**Code:**

```
 var result = list
   .GroupBy(item => RoundToMinutes(item.Date, 15))
   .Select(group => new {
      at   = group.Key,
      best = group.Aggregate((s, a) => 
        Math.Abs((s.Time - group.Key).TotalSeconds) < 
        Math.Abs((a.Time - group.Key).TotalSeconds) 
         ? s 
         : a) 
    })
   .Select(group => new MyObject() {
      ID    = group.at,
      Value = group.best.Value,
      Time  = group.best.Key
    }) 
   .ToList(); // materialization if required
```

Comment: This is good but it takes first value... So in the result set is taken value from 20:11:27, instead of value from 20:17:00 which is much closer to 20:15:00

Comment: @Josef: I see; so you want to take an item from `group` which has the *closest* `Time` to `group.Key`, i.e. the `best` item such that `best.Time - group.Key` has the minium possible value